# How to make Slider translates left to right in Swiper JS?

Tags: slider, slideshow, swiper.js

I'm trying to work with Swiper Js to make an autoplay slider. But I wanna make a slider that is translated from left to right ( Default Right To Left ).

When I pass attribute reverseDirection everything is going well, but when I try to add pagination and that's what happens, the pagination is the first-child and goes last-child ?

So how can I reverse this pagination or have a solution to make Swiper Slide LTR, thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried reverseDirection: true in autoplay property in Swiper options? That worked perfectly for me.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: yap edited, now

Comment: This one is already the answer for this question

Comment: so, you want to reverse the pagination. My bad.